# How do we prevent our app from being installed on multiple devices with the same Apple ID?

Tags: ios

We have found that many of our customers are downloading our app with a single Apple ID and installing it on multiple iPad devices. For example, five iPads share a single Apple ID and the same app license. We would prefer that all five users (employees) purchase their own license. How do we prevent our app from being used by multiple users sharing the same Apple ID?

Comment: Short answer: You can't.  A user is entitled to use a purchased product across their devices.  Apple has some protection against account sharing by limiting the number of times you can switch the iTunes account on a device, but if the 5 devices are all using the same Apple ID and never switch Apple ID, then they all belong to the same user as far as Apple is concerned.  If you have your own account system in your app and each employee has their own account you could look at moving to a consumable in-app purchase where a purchase is linked to a single account in your back end

Comment: If you don't have accounts in your back end or the employee shares the same account then there isn't much you can do there.  You could set up some sort of server so that each time your app launches it sends a silent push to other instances of your app linked to the same Apple ID and they enter a 'locked' state with a message that the app is in use on another device.